# Register DLL using RegSvr32 in Java - How to hide alert appear

Tags: java, dll, regsvr32

I'm having a problem with dll registration by RegSvr32. Everything is done programmatically under Java before applications starts. My question is:

Is there any solution to disable alert appear with result of DLL registration? It's a prompt with "OK" button.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `regsvr32 /?` at a command prompt shows (as with most commands) the options that are available - well, in this case, it shows an error, but also says what options are available.

[image]

Looks like `/s` would fit the bill.